# Can you Export edited textures out of Blender?

Tags: texturing, export

I'm not sure how to describe it in one sentence for the title.

But I really mean is that for example:

I add an image texture to the material> Base color, I slot inbetween the 2 nodes a Hue/Saturation Node. Its it possible to export the texture WITH the Hue/Saturation Node changes??[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. It's called texture baking.
In this case you'd use an *Emission shader*, to avoid shadows

1. Connect your *Hue/Saturation* node into an *Emission shader*
2. Add a new empty image texture (don't connect it to anything)
3. Go *RenderTab > Bake > Bake Type > Emit* and hit <kbd>Bake</kbd>

Now just select the baked image in the *Image editor* and save it

[image]

Comment: Notice , you just copied my style............

Comment: how did you make that Bake symbol , i also need that in some my awnsere/

Comment: Oh, sorry mate, must've overlooked your answer :). The bake button is done like this <kbd>Bake</kbd>. How did you do that emoticon?

Comment: https://getemoji.com/     <kbd>CTRL C</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Referring to what you have told in the question , i am assuming that you have an image texture , you did something to it , and now you want to take it out as another image, well thats called **texture baking** , what you need to do is to open the image editor (i hope you know how to )

[image]

and then in your node tree , **Add an image texture and create a new image , name it whatever you want and DONT connect it to anything**.Then Switch to cycles renderer , apply the material to a plain and then in the render settings , go to bake , and give it a Diffuse Bake , **Not combined** bake. Then you will see in the image editor , that your black image has turned into the result of your node tree. Click on image>Save as to export it as a jpeg or png.